# ASP.NET - Create a SAS Dataset

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sas

Sorry for the open ended question as I have no idea where to start or of this can even be done.  I have an web application built using ASP.NET with a SQL Server database.  We have a user request to provide an 'Export to SAS Dataset' feature.  Is this something I can do in .NET or is there a SAS Server/Service solution to create a SAS Dataset?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

CozyRoc has a library to read/write SAS datasets from .NET.  It's not free and it seems to be part of their SSIS tools.  http://www.cozyroc.com/ssis/sas-data-source

The problem is that the SAS Data Set format is binary and proprietary.  As far as I know, the guys above reverse engineered the format.

If that is not an option, you may have to provide an XML or CSV file and the user will have to import that into SAS.